# How can I get the string message in describe and it block displayed on console running protractor?

Tags: protractor

I am very new to jasmine, mocha and protractor...I have to debug some javascript code in protractor framework, and when I run the test, the message in describe and it block never get reported/displayed on console.

Here is an example:

```
describe('test case 1 - online ordering',function() {
      it(' check all the steps for online ordering',function() {

      }
}
```

I thought the message in `describe` and the block both get displayed when I run the test on console.

I run it like this:

```
grunt myTestcase
```

Comment: console.log("your message"); didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

For printing on console, you need put *jasmineNodeOpts* on conf.js file and then run:

```
Code Snippet:

         jasmineNodeOpts: {
             // If true, print colors to the terminal.
             showColors: true,
             // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
             defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
             //Function called to print jasmine results.
             print: function() {},
         },
```